# iOS GAI-Tracker (Google Analytics) prevent https-calls

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for iOS to track my app usage.

I also try to prevent my app from making any https-calls, so I don't have to go through the export-compliance hassle when submitting the app (https-calls require to mention that the app uses encryption. And then I need to make some self declaration notice to some US-Bureau at the end of the year - can't remember which one exactly).

So, I found this:

```
[tracker set:kGAIUseSecure value:[@NO stringValue]];
```

Which does seem to work when I dispatch a page view to the tracker.

However, when the app starts up, Instruments tells me that my app is making a request to some verisign-server through port 443 (https).

I'm initializing the tracker like this:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].optOut = ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kAllowTracking];
    // Initialize Google Analytics with a 120-second dispatch interval. There is a
    // tradeoff between battery usage and timely dispatch.
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20; // for testing purposes set to low interval
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"myTracker"
                                              trackingId:kTrackingId];
```

When I comment this out, there's no https-call when the app starts up, so I assume it's the Google-tracker which issues the call.
But there's no way to tell the shared instance NOT to make any https-calls (just as mentioned above in the subsequent calls).

Any ideas how to get around this? I really want to avoid the export-compliance stuff.

Comment: Where did you get this information ?! There is no need to make any declaration to anyone for using https, that would be ridiculous. On the contrary, you should make sure that your app uses **only** https, this is the best practice and best way to protect the privacy of your users.

Comment: Ok so after reading stuff here and there (see [this](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Export%20Compliance)), it does seem that in theory you need to make this self-declaration to the US government. I can't find anything that says that you're exempted if using only https in an iOS app. But as far as I know, nobody does that (except maybe big companies). Also if you're not a US citizen I wouldn't worry too much about it, the worst that can happen to you is having your app removed from the App Store and I doubt very much this will happen.

Comment: Whatever you decide, please remember that removing https from your app goes against **everything** the industry has bee trying to enforce over the past few years. Also, Apple has already announced that using https only will be mandatory in the very near future.

Comment: @deadbeef: it IS ridiculous ;) And I know that using https IS the industry standard nowadays. But as stated in the documents, if your app uses https, you're obligated to do this self classification report every year in January <a href="https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/reports-and-reviews/annual-self-classification">here</a>. This is a dealbreaker and I'm thinking about abandoning creating such apps entirely. It's an app for a bigger company. And if Apple removes the app from the store because of this, I'd be doomed. So the question remains: how to get rid of https?

Comment: Sorry to insist, but I think you're going at it the wrong way. If you're working for a big company, then tell them that in order to be 100% compliant they need to file this report. Also tell them that removing https would be a **VERY BAD IDEA** and that it is far more likely that Apple will refuse your app for not using https than the opposite. Then let them choose. And if they go with https, then filing the report is the job of their legal department not yours.

Comment: Well, I'm basically with you on this. But consider the following: the company is located in Switzerland. The app is important, but not THAT important to them. I don't know whether their legal department has the capacity to go through this. So they might also dump the app entirely (bad for me). I don't wanna start an argument with you about this - it IS a stupid thing to require this for non US-Devs just because the app uses https (which is basically forced on us).

Comment: I get your point. But the way I see it, if you're a contractor, your job is to give them all the information along with your best advice. Also, you seem to be very concerned about this particular US legislation, but what about other legislations form other countries ? I don't know about Switzerland, but in France for example (and maybe the entire EU) I'm pretty sure it would be illegal to send Google Analytics data to the US without user consent. Doing it over plain http would be even worse. In theory, there are also also filings to make when you collect and export user data outside the EU.

Comment: Getting user consent about tracking is a whole other story. France a different beast (import regulations). I'll let them know what the issue is and tell them that the best way to get around this would be to remove the Google-Tracker (I personally don't like that anyway). Thanks for taking the time, though...

Comment: My point was that if you want to be 100% legal you're probably way over your head anyway. But you seem to understand very well the situation you're in so I'll stop bothering you and let you choose for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
    NSError *configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
    NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
// Optional: configure GAI options.
    GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
    gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;

    return YES;
}



 **//and then you initialise  GAI Tracker in Your Method**
 **//call below method with required parameter**
```

-(void)sendGAITracker:(NSString*)trackerName, trackingID:(NSString *)trackingIdValue{

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

  id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
 [tracker send:[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:trackerName trackingId: trackingIdValue]]

 });
```

}